# How to delete a DNS record using Softlayer API with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to write a PowerShell script, which deletes DNS record from Softlayer cloud, using Softlayer REST API.

The below command should do my purpose. I have `$headers` correctly setup. My issue is with `$uri` and `$jsonObject`.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method POST -ContentType application/json -Body $jsonObject
```

can anybody please give me an example of values for `$jsonObject` and `$uri`? 
Should `$uri` be like below? If yes, what is the `Object.json` , do I need to define it?

```
$uri = "https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/deleteObject/Object.json"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how:
$uri="https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/$domainID/getResourceRecords.json"

Below will return a json file which has all records in our domain:
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method GET -ContentType application/json

From received json file ,we can extract record ID ($recordID in below) of the record that we want to delete and then run below: 
$deleteResoutceURI= "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/$recordID/deleteObject.json"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $deleteResoutceURI -Headers $headers -Method POST -ContentType application/json

Answer (score 0):

Try following the example

```
 slcli --format=json call-api SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord deleteObject --id 123456789
```

the 123456789 data should change with your DNS domain id

For more information, could you review the link https://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/call_api/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your reply. The link and command you provided is for Python API and thus not working in PowerShell.